# Checking whether various form fields are filled in

Tags: javascript, validation, form

This is a customer information data entry form. First name and Last name are required. In addition phone number, e-mail and birth date are used to check the database for existing customers with the same information.

Either of these fields (phone, e-mail or birth date) can be empty or filled in. In order to validate against database I need to check if the user has filled each field in or not.

Is there a way to refactor the code and still set a different property for each scenario?

The code looks like this:

```
var sFirstName = Inputs.GetProperty("sFirstName");
var sLastName = Inputs.GetProperty("sLastName");
var sEmail = Inputs.GetProperty("sEmail");
var sPhone = Inputs.GetProperty("sPhone");
var sBirthDate = Inputs.GetProperty("sBirthDate");
var sCoAddress = Inputs.GetProperty("sCoAddress");
var sAddress = Inputs.GetProperty("sAddress");
var sZip = Inputs.GetProperty("sZip");
var sCity = Inputs.GetProperty("sCity");

if(!sFirstName || !sLastName){
    TheApplication().RaiseErrorText("First name and last name are required");           
}

if(!sEmail && (!sCoAddress || !sAddress || !sZip || !sCity)){
    TheApplication().RaiseErrorText("Please enter either e-mail or postal address");
}
if(sEmail && sBirthDate && sPhone){
    Outputs.SetProperty("QueryAll","Y");
}
else if(sEmail && sBirthDate && !sPhone){
    Outputs.SetProperty("QueryEmailBday","Y");
}
else if(sEmail && !sBirthDate && sPhone){
    Outputs.SetProperty("QueryEmailPhone","Y");
}
else if(!sEmail && sBirthDate && sPhone){
    Outputs.SetProperty("QueryBdayPhone","Y");
}
else if(sEmail && !sBirthDate && !sPhone){
    Outputs.SetProperty("QueryEmail","Y");
}
else if(!sEmail && sBirthDate && !sPhone){
    Outputs.SetProperty("QueryBirthDate","Y");
}
else if(!sEmail && !sBirthDate && sPhone){
    Outputs.SetProperty("QueryPhone","Y");
}
else if(!sEmail && !sBirthDate && !sPhone){
    Outputs.SetProperty("QueryNameOnly","Y");
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You've come to the right place, what you've written there is a maintainability-disaster waiting to happen.

Comment: You might want to provide some information about `Input` and `GetProperty`. They don't look like native JS (they look like from a Windows platform given the capital-case syntax). Giving a bit of context about your system may allow for better solutions.

Comment: Can't you just query all the information all the time if you have their the required fields?

Comment: This would be a lot easier if your Queries would have strict names. So QueryBday instead of QueryBirthDate - in that case you could just build the query name.

Comment: What happens next? What do you do with `QueryAll`, `QueryEmailBday`, etc.?

Comment: Hey guys. Thanks for all the feedback and sorry for the terrible code. I'm as new to this as I am to CodeReview. The code is actually Siebel eScript so the Input is a property set containing the fields and values (kind of like an XML structure). To pick out the values I use GetProperty. 
The 'QueryAll', 'QueryEmailBday' variables are passed to a Siebel Workflow which then queries a customer database for matching values. The query string cannot query on fields with null values because then Siebel will return records which also have null values in those fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve this by constructing your Queryname dynamically:

```
var queryName = "Query";
if ( sEmail ) queryName += "Email";
if ( sBDay  ) queryName += "BDay";
if ( sPhone ) queryName += "Phone";

if ( queryName == "Query" ) queryName = "QueryNameOnly";

Outputs.SetProperty( queryName,"Y" );
```

But for this you would have to be a little more strict with your Parameter-Names not changing between BDay and BithDate and no Specialcase for ALL

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to (as [@](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/46500/falco)[Falco](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/46500/falco) commented, and [answered](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/120153/refactor-else-if-structure-to-check-values-in-form-fields#120177),) change your "*Property*"<sup>^</sup> names - you could also use a look-up table concept (implemented as a dictionary object):

```
var params = {
    "sEmail"        :   "Email",
    "sPhone"        :   "Phone",
    "sBirthDate"    :   "BDay"
};
```

<sup>**^** Note: As [@](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/46500/falco)[Falco](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/46500/falco) implied, these are more correctly 'parameters' or arguments, than [properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method#JavaScript_example).</sup>

This makes it **far** more maintainable than a page of if-else blocks.